# Symantec cer file for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I have received a `*.cer` file from my hosting service `1and1`. The certificate is for my domain. There is very little documentation involved and I need to get it running for my Apache webserver to support `https`.

The file starts with

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERTIFICATE&STRING&HERE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How can I create all the required cert files for apache?
On another server hosted by another provider I have configured `https` with three different files.

```
SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/file.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/file.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/path/to/file.ca-bundle"
```

I am confused because the second provider obviously supplied a public (crt) and private key (key) whereas now I only have the cer file. In fact I could download another cer file called intermediate. Is the first one (`1.cer`) the private key and can I create the public key out of `1.cer` and the `intermediate.cer` file or is `1.cer` the public key and I can create the private out of both.

The documentation only says:

*To use an SSL certificate managed by you, you must download the private key from the Domain Center, then install the intermediate certificate, private key, and public key on the server. The root certificate is a self-signed certification authority certificate, which creates with the intermediate and SSL certificates "a certificate chain".*

What's going on here?

Comment: You need to edit your question and describe the process leading up to the issuance of the `*.cer` file.  Did you send a request file (`*.csr` or `*.req`) to 1&1.  Or did you use a web interface?  In the latter case, were you given the option to save a private key?  The CA bundle will be downloadable from the CA's website.

Comment: adding to @garethTheRed's comment: if you sent a `*.csr` request to 1&1, then you already have the `private.key` file - you had to have it in order to create the certificate request (`*.csr`). So you want to use that `private.key` file (probably it's not called `private.key` but something else).

Comment: The minimun you will need is the key and signed cert, if your provider sends you just a cert, it is certainly not to host a server.